# RenderAction - Using it without influence to parent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

If I call RenderAction on action method which view has Html.BeginForm() with no params my form action folows the parent url.

If I add any param (route values, action, etc) , form action attribute is replaced with MyChildContorller's controller name and action.

How to use RenderAction without affecting parent url?

Comment: Perhaps you want RenderPartial() instead?

Answer (score 0):

`Html.BeginForm()` simply puts `Request.Url.ToString()` in the form `action` parameter. When you use `Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName")` routing will be used to calculate the url.